# Proof of Turan's theorem

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics

I'm following the proof of Turan's theorem on $\text{ex}(n,K^r)$ in [Diestel's Graph Theory book](http://books.google.ch/books?id=aR2TMYQr2CMC&lpg=PP1&dq=graph%20theory%20diestel&hl=fr&pg=PA166#v=onepage&q&f=false) (click to see the page) and something bothers me:

> Since $G$ is edge-maximal without a $K^r$ subgraph, $G$ has a subgraph
>   $K=K^{r-1}$. By the induction hypothesis, $G-K$ has at most
>   $t_{r-1}(n-r+1)$ edges [...]

But why would $G-K$ be $K^{r-1}-$free ? Couldn't there be other $K^{r-1}$ disjoint subgraphs in $G$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof does not claim that $G-K$ is $K^{r-1}$-free, only that it is $K^r$-free. The induction is on $n$, not on $r$, so the assumption is that all smaller $K^r$-free graphs have been classified.